# What to use instead validator in jaxb 2.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb

JAXB version 1 spec have a Validator object, in version 2 Validator object was deprecated and optional. What do I need to use instead Validator object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JAXB 2.0, the setValidating() method has been deprecated. Now, schema validation is performed using the JAXP 1.3 validation API. To validate using JAXB 2.0, create a SchemaFactory

For an example see the [Validator Section here](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/jaxb/index3.html)